# How can I make bg-header-top visible on mobile?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a template that uses  and I used it to implement a multi-language select. Problem is: when i switch to mobile view the top-header disappears and only the navbar stays. Does anyone have an idea how i can keep the top-header? Template uses Bootstrap 3

```
<body>
<div class="box-layout">
    <header class="header-style-1">
        <div class="bg-header-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="header-top">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <a href="index.html"><img src="../assets/images/index/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="header-top-right pull-right">
                                    <ul class="header-contact">
                                        <li>
                                            <i class="flaticon-vibrating-phone"></i>
                                            <div class="h-adress-content">
                                                <h6>Telefon</h6>
                                                <p>XXXXXXXXX</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- .h-adress-content -->
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <i class="flaticon-placeholder"></i>
                                            <div class="h-adress-content">
                                                <h6>Adresse</h6>
                                                <p>XXXXXXXXXX</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- .h-adress-content -->
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="h-adress-content">
                                                <p><a href="index.html" class="current_language active"><img src="../assets/images/index/de.png"> DE</a></p> 
                                                <p><a href="../pl/index.html" class="current_language"><img src="../assets/images/index/pl.png"> PL</a></p> 
                                            </div> 
                                            <!-- .h-adress-content -->
                                        </li> `
```

Comment: can u share here what you have tried, so that we can see what is going wrong. Please read: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There isn't any bootstrap visibility classes in the HTML, so I would recommend inspecting the header top div using the browsers developer console and see what CSS is hiding it and then override it with your own CSS. I don't recommend this, but if you are struggling you could just do `.header-top { display:block!important }` or whichever element is being hidden.